# How to display data value on each slice of doughnut charts in echarts

Tags: vue.js, charts, highcharts, echarts

I am using echarts for my charting needs and want to display the value/text of each slice in a doughnut chart on the slice. I have gone through the configuartion options but could not find the solution.

Here is the chart echart provides and the one I want:

[image: Available in echarts]

The one I need:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In series, you can add `itemStyle`

```
            itemStyle : {
                normal : {
                     label : {
                        show: true, position: 'inner',
                        formatter : function (params){
                              return  params.value + '%\n'
                        },
                    },
                    labelLine : {
                        show : false
                    }
                },
```

You can try following code online at [here](https://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example/pie2.html#-en):

```
option = {
    tooltip : {
        trigger: 'item',
        formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)"
    },
    legend: {
        orient : 'vertical',
        x : 'left',
        data:['直接访问','邮件营销','联盟广告','视频广告','搜索引擎']
    },
    toolbox: {
        show : true,
        feature : {
            mark : {show: true},
            dataView : {show: true, readOnly: false},
            magicType : {
                show: true, 
                type: ['pie', 'funnel'],
                option: {
                    funnel: {
                        x: '25%',
                        width: '50%',
                        funnelAlign: 'center',
                        max: 1548
                    }
                }
            },
            restore : {show: true},
            saveAsImage : {show: true}
        }
    },
    calculable : true,
    series : [
        {
            name:'访问来源',
            type:'pie',
            radius : ['50%', '70%'],
            itemStyle : {
                normal : {
                     label : {
                        show: true, position: 'inner',
                        formatter : function (params){
                              return  params.value + '%\n'
                        },
                    },
                    labelLine : {
                        show : false
                    }
                },
                emphasis : {
                    label : {
                        show : true,
                        position : 'center',
                        textStyle : {
                            fontSize : '30',
                            fontWeight : 'bold'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            data:[
                {value:335, name:'直接访问'},
                {value:310, name:'邮件营销'},
                {value:234, name:'联盟广告'},
                {value:135, name:'视频广告'},
                {value:1548, name:'搜索引擎'}
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks much for taking time to answer it, I was using echarts from apache. Is it possible with it?

Comment: I think they're pretty similar. You can try at https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-doughnut